# WordPress Image not showing up when searching the website but title and article button do

Tags: php, wordpress, custom-wordpress-pages

I am trying to fix a fault in my website, when a user searches an article the title and button show but the article image does not, the image of the search result is below. The code below displays the title and the button, does anyone know how I can locate the code to get the image also?

(Below is the previous code) Code 1

```
<a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php the_title_attribute(); ? 
>"><?php the_title(); ?></a>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

So the code to retrieve the images using PHP is:

```
<?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?>
```

(Displayed within the code)

```
<a id="featuredimg" href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php 
the_title_attribute(); ?>"> <?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?><br> <?php the_title(); 
?> </a>
```